# How to watch a change on the scrollWidth property of the an element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to perform a function when the `scrollWidth` value change on a property using vanilla JavaScript.

I tried the following but that does not work

```
var container = document.getElementById('my-container');
container.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    if (e.offsetHeight < e.scrollHeight) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

I also tried

```
var container = document.getElementById('my-container');
container.watch('scrollWidth', function (e) {
    // do something with container
});
```

But none seem to be working. How can I correctly watch for a change in the `scrollWidth` property of the `container`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an event that fires on changes to scrollHeight or scrollWidth in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835219/is-there-an-event-that-fires-on-changes-to-scrollheight-or-scrollwidth-in-jquery) Note that it asks for jQuery but the accepted answer does not use jQuery.