# Ember event rendering property in dom

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a standard Ember view with a template.

Template:

```
<script type="text/html" data-template-name="template">
  <div id="container">
    <p>{{{view.description}}}</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

View:

```
Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'OutlookSnapshotInformationTemplate',
  description : "Loooooong text...",
  descriptionChanged : function(){
    $('container').height()
    [...]
  }.observes('description')
}),
```

I want to get the dimension of *container* div, using JQuery using descriptionChanged observer.

The problem is that description value is asynchronous and is updated before the rendering of the page.

There is an event that is raised on specific property in a template is re-rendered in DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your observer, interact with the DOM inside of a call to `Ember.run.scheduleOnce()`.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_scheduleOnce

This ensures that the given code runs after the render queue has been flushed, and further that it will only run once if you happen to update description multiple times in the current run loop:

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function () {
  var height = this.$('#container').height();
  // ...
  // profit!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`didInsertElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) method of your view:

```
App.YourView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'OutlookSnapshotInformationTemplate',
  description : "Loooooong text...",
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.set('containerHeight', this.$('#container').height());
    console.log(this.get('containerHeight'));
  }
}),
```

Comment: Yes i know *didInsertElement*, but is called only one time in the lifeCycle of view and the description can change few time during the visualization.

Comment: Yes, but you can still keep your observer. The idea was to set the `containerHeight` property of the view in `didInsertElement` so that the observer can access it.

Comment: But the problem is that the height could be incorrect at when the view is rendered or when the Description change in the model.
Only when it changes in the DOM will be correct

Comment: That is true, but what you could do is in your `didInsertElement` hook you could set up a listener for a resize event like suggested [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div).

Comment: The post say that is impossible to receive an event that is raised from dynamically content change. One solution is a polling system, that is not a good way to solve the problem.
Ember & jquery are good together a part when u need to synchronize, that's why is better use the solution proposed by @ahaurw01