# CSS - Changing width relative to height

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website right now and I need some help. I have one particular section where I want the height to be 79.6% of the body and I want the width of that div to be based off of the height. I've only been able to find ways to change height based off of width though so far. Does anybody out there know how to make sure an element keeps the same aspect ratio based on its height?

Comment: Best to look here first [event listener on div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a 4:3 scaling ratio based on the element height. This code is untested, comment if you need further help.

```
var ratioX = 4;
var ratioY = 3;

var eleHeight = $('#targetElement').height();
var scale = eleHeight/ratioY;
var eleWidth = scale * ratioX;

$('#targetElement').width(eleWidth);
```

You can add a resize event and wrap it into a function, so whenever browser is resized your image will scale proportionally. If you need a css answer, i am not aware of any techniques.