# Get Height Change of body without using resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get an event to call when the `body` or `document` of an HTML page changes size without the use of jQuerys `$(window).resize()` event.

The reason I can't use the `resize` event is because this document or webpage will be inframed within another page.

Is there a way to have an event called if the size of the `body` or `document` changes other than `resize()` event? I would prefer to avoid a `Timeout` I am using that now, but am looking to replace it.

I apologize for not including any code, the only code I have tried is the following and after much research found that this will not work.

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
  console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: OT: reize = resize ;)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div

Comment: Ill have to check that out.

Comment: @Robert NOthing, there was a little literal mistake in Your code, but someone edited it ;)