# show image when div height is change using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, height, show-hide

I have an image in column right and a `div` in column left. Now i want to keep the image hidden, and it should only show up when `div` height reach 650px.

I have done some googling and came up that it can be achieved with `if else`statement in jquery. But didn't find correct breakthrough.

Please suggest.

Comment: what about media queries in css ? it is better than using javaScript in the firstplace ,

Comment: You're right but it is not about screen height and the website is NOT responsive. I am not looking at responsive measures, i just want to show an image when div height is increased. Till then it should stay hidden.

Comment: what does change the div height in the first place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use media queries in your css file no need for jquery in the first place

```
@media(max-height:650px){
 #img-id{
  display:none;
 }
}
```

However as you sated that it is a div element you can use jquery

as stated in this question 
[jquery resize listener on a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div)

As the thread poelinca provided suggests, there are some nice plugins available for this functionality.

If you don't like the plugin idea, another simple solution would be to simply trigger a "resize" event on the div whenever the content is modified. Then you could monitor it with resize() as expected, utilizing an elegant observer pattern.

```
function appendContent($div, content) {
   $div.append(content).trigger($.Event('resize'));
}

$div.bind('resize', function(e) {
   // all your magic resize mojo goes here
});
```

so I would modify it into

```
    function appendContent($div, content) {
   $div.append(content).trigger($.Event('resize'));
}

$div.bind('resize', function(e) {
if( $('divLeft').height() >= 650){ 
    $("#img-id").hide();
  }
else {
$("#img-id").show();
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something with `.toggle()` like this:

```
$('img').toggle(function(){
     return $('divLeft').height() >= 650;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If u use media query,you can do somthing like this..

```
@media(min-height:650px){
 #image-id{
  visibility: visible
 }
}
```

and outer the media query or inside `@media(min-height:650px)` line, give

```
#image-id{
  visibility:hidden
 }
```

Hope will helpfull....