# jQuery Event on image resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to trigger an event if my image size changes.

```
$("img#test").bind("resize",function(){
    console.log("saadsdsaadsasdsaijashjadshsakjhsakjasn");
});
```

This isn´t working. How would it work?

Comment: is $("img#test") recognized ? maybe a stupid comment but you didn't provide other code

Comment: if the image is <img src="img/blabla.jpg" id="test"> maybe you shoud use 
$("#test")

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `resize()` event in jquery

```
$("img#test").resize(function(){
    console.log("saadsdsaadsasdsaijashjadshsakjhsakjasn");
});
```

Comment: not sure the onresize event is supported for chrome/firefox img elements. ie seems to work tho