# JQuery add listening event to .resizable() then append DIV's

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my admin panel I am building I have a quick access side panel to the right which is resizeable using the JQuery resizeable function, see below;

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').resizable({
    handles: 'w',
    minWidth: 300,
    maxWidth: 650
});
```

It has a menu at the top which on page load looks like the below snippet;

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#quick_sidebar_tab_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
            Staff
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#quick_sidebar_tab_2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
            Messages
            <span class="badge badge-success">7</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    // APPEND LI TO/FROM HERE

    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            More
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">

            // APPEND TO/FROM FIRST LI FROM BELOW

            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#quick_sidebar_tab_3" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell-o"> </i> Alerts </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#quick_sidebar_tab_3" data-toggle="tab">
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"> </i> Notifications </a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;" data-target="#quick_sidebar_tab_3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### QUESTIONS

How do I add a listening event for when the DIV is being resized.

Upon knowing the above, I believe I would simply add a check to see what the width is and upon it reaching a certain width, append one of the `<li>` elsewhere.

How can I append my `<li>` to and from the commented areas of the above list?

### UPDATE

After Korgrue help, I have part of the code I will be needing and have updated the [live version](http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/index123.html);

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').bind('resize', function(e) {
    if ($(this).width() >= 400) {
        alert('Append the menu item');
    }
});
```

### UPDATE II

Ball is now rolling...

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').bind('resize', function(e) {
    if ($(this).width() >= 400) {
        $('.Testing1234').insertBefore('li.dropdown');
        $('.Testing1234 i').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: And what would "More" link to? What's the expected content/behavior?

Comment: @Webomatik, underneath the list, first paragraph "the 'More' drop down", you click and it shows the additional items, the second tier.

Comment: Ha, I get it, upon resizing, you want to toggle hide/show for the dropdown-menu UL

Comment: @Webomatik -- No, I already have that; upon resizing, I want items in the more second tier area to appear on the first tier and visa-versa when decreasing the width.

Comment: @Webomatik please see this [live version](http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/index123.html) to aid understanding.

Comment: The answer to your first question relates to setting up an observer. How to do this is answered in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div

Comment: @Korgrue when editing my question I came across this however I don't quite understand it whereas I have tried adding this script onto my page placing an alert within however nothing happens.

Comment: @TimMarshall - the only part you will need in that mess is this:

`$('.Quick-Sidebar').bind('resize', function(e) {
   // all your magic resize mojo goes here
});`

That will set up your resize observer on that div.

Comment: @Korgrue I've just updated my question thanks to your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1). Listening For The Div To Be Resized

Upon the administrator expanding their quick access sidebar greater than or equal to 400px, there is enough room for the 'Alerts' tab to be shown on the first tier so we need to first listen;

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').bind('resize', function(e) {
    if ($(this).width() >= 400) {
        // What to do IF the width is greater than or equal to 400px?
    }
});
```

### 2). Moving The 'Alerts' `<li>`

I gave each `<li>` a class name as I just found it easier this way although you could count how many `<li>` there are, minus one and call that. So I move it upon the width reaching 400 and then reversing visa-versa;

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').bind('resize', function(e) {
    if ($(this).width() >= 400) {
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts').insertBefore('li.dropdown');
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts i').hide();
    }
    if ($(this).width() <= 399) {
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts').insertBefore('ul.dropdown-menu li:first');
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts i').show();
    }
});
```

### 3). Repeat For All Tab Options

You could do so via set intervals, setting a var, checking if width is var +/- 100px or so, however I've gone for adding one upon enough room being available straight away;

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').bind('resize', function(e) {
    if ($(this).width() >= 400) {
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts').insertBefore('li.dropdown');
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts i').hide();
    }
    if ($(this).width() <= 399) {
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts').insertBefore('ul.dropdown-menu li:first');
        $('.QSB-NM-Alerts i').show();
    }

    if ($(this).width() >= 575) {
        $('.QSB-NM-Notify').insertBefore('li.dropdown');
        $('.QSB-NM-Notify i').hide();
        $('.QSB-NM-Divider').hide();
    }
    if ($(this).width() <= 574) {
        $('.QSB-NM-Notify').insertBefore('ul.dropdown-menu .QSB-NM-Divider');
        $('.QSB-NM-Notify i').show();
        $('.QSB-NM-Divider').show();
    }
});
```

### 4). Removing the 'More' drop down tab

I'm not sure if I'll need this however upon there only being one additional tab left, you would need to repeat the above and simply hide/show 'More' tab.