# Conditional values in css

Tags: css

```
.elem{
    width: 20%;
    text-orientation: if width < 100px then upright else inherit

}
```

Is there a css only way to do something like this? The example is weird but that's not the point

**is there a way to make a css value that depends on a condition that gets checked at each repaint?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with CSS only.

You could use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), but that would *only* allow you to act upon the `width` of the `window`, not on a particular element. The only way you could listen for `width` changes on a particular element is via Javascript. If you are using JQuery, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053583/jquery-resize-listener-on-a-div) should make your life easier.