# How do I add a resize event to an article in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

```
events:
    'click textarea': 'composeComment'
    'click .submit': 'submit'
    'blur textarea': 'textareaBlur'
    'resize article': 'repositionBoards'


repositionBoards: ->
    #this is my own function, i just need it to be called everytime an article's size changes
    board.align()
```

How do I get my `repositionBoards` method called on resize events?

Answer (score 8):

The [`resize` event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) is sent to `window`:

> The `resize` event is sent to the `window` element when the size of the browser window changes

But a Backbone view's events are bound to the view's `el` using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). The view's `el` won't get a `resize` event so putting `'resize articule': 'repositionBoards'` in your view's `events` won't do any good.

If you need to get the `resize` event in your view, you'll have to bind it to `window` yourself:

```
initialize: (options) ->
    $(window).on('resize', this.repositionBoards)
remove: ->
    $(window).off('resize', this.repositionBoards) # Clean up after yourself.
    @$el.remove() # The default implementation does this.
    @
repositionBoards: ->
    # Use => if you need to worry about what `@` is
    board.align()
```

Also note the addition of a [`remove`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-remove) so that you can unbind your `resize` handler. You will, of course, want to use `view.remove()` to remove your view or just don't worry about it if that view is your whole application.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer.

My only concern is that my articles' sizes change when text is entered into them. When the size expands, I want to call reposition boards. But since resize is sent to the window, this does me no good.

Do you know if there are any events that can be tied to the resizing of an article or div? Just when it expands like when the height or width increases.

Thanks again.

Comment: @user1489926: But there is no resize event on anything other than the window, AFAIK you have to do it the hard way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/172821/479863