# How do I run a function after fadeIn without a callback?

Tags: jquery, function, callback, fadein

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting when a div's height changes using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery)
>   [jQuery: Get height of hidden element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery)

Is there a way to detect the completion of a fadeIn event with jQuery so I can fire a function on completion?

I understand fadeIn has a built in callback function but this requires me to directly affect the fadeIn code. I don't have access to that code so I want to add an event listener or something to detect when an item has faded in.

The reason I want to do this is because I have some code that detects the height of a div, but on pageload this div element is hidden. I want to detect the height of the div after it is faded in.

Comment: poll the visibility/opacity of it in an interval?

Comment: @Antonio, does the code that calls `fadeIn()` always run before your own code?

Comment: it runs on click. I then want to get the height of the element. I'm only having problems because it starts off with the CSS of display:none I just need the height of that div.

Comment: @Antonio, better see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery), then.

Answer (score -1):

You could utilise the DOMAttrModified event, although this will depend on the browsers you need to support as it's still quite experimental.

But since jQuery's `animate()` changes the `style` attribute of element(s), it's suitable.

```
//your code
var div = $('#some_div'), target_height = 100;
div.on('DOMAttrModified', function(evt) {
    if ($(this).height() == target_height) do_something();
});

//some code in another, untouchable script
$('#some_div').animate({height: 100});
```