# slideToggle to move the div up above the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As shown on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMhsb/1/), clicking on top, it toggles the `<div>` below.

What I tried to do is this: On clicking "TOP"/ black box, 
that div and the div below should come up and overlay on text.

As `#ppForm` `<div>` pushing `#we` `<div>` to open upwards vertically.

It is when `#ppForm` opens it should push the div upwards vertically...

Comment: What does the last sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the style of these two elements and now [it seems to work as needed](http://jsfiddle.net/AMhsb/4/):

```css
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#ppForm {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:120%; /* instead of top:0; */
}
```

Comment: thanks this is what i wanted... I tried it a lot in different ways but couldn't make it.. :)

Comment: one more thing @Stano, i want we div to be pushed up when div opens up. i.e. on click of TOP the div should open up from bottom and push TOP div upwards.

Comment: Thanks. If you change the style back to `#ppForm {position:relative;}`, it will shift the div up. Only problem is the page is not scrolling to the bottom. [I was looking for some solution and found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery): [Ben Alman's resize plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/docs/files/jquery-ba-resize-js.html), it can be used when some element is resized. [Updated fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/AMhsb/6/). I don't think it's ideal solution, but dunno other way to stick the div at the bottom.

Comment: thanks for the input, it's the way i want, but onClick the TOP div should go up as heading and the yellow div in the bottom. Such that TOP become's heading and shifts to top.

Comment: @harnish Great :), I also tried to modify it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/AMhsb/8/), but it's much better that you made it by yourself without that additional plugin! :-) Btw, the console says 'e is not defined', so either add the e event, or delete e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#we').click(function () {
   $("#ppForm").css('position','absolute').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Or maybe you mean something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/JMrRh/)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like this:

Keep your `<div id="ppForm"></div>` after `<div id="we">` and try