# How do i set div height to another DIV using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Updated:**

I have the situation like,  Having 3 column layout Column A, Column B, Column C. Column A height will be dynamic one. I need to set Column A height  for both Column B and C .

For example, Column A  has  tabbed panel which is having height based on tab content. I have the issue with monitoring Column A height for Column B and C. I am thinking of using setTimeOut Method to monitor Column A height. Is there best way to do ?

**Code:**

```
 setTimeout(set_height,1);
function set_height(){
cmn_height = $('.column-a').height();
$(".column-b").css('height',cmn_height);
$(".column-c").css('height',cmn_height);
cmn_height=0;
}
```

Kindly advice

Comment: If you are using jQuery (judging by the tag), perhaps this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery

Comment: Why are not using this on on page load and why are you using setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
setInterval("set_height()",1000);

function set_height(){
    cmn_height = $('.column-a').height();
    $(".column-b").css('height',cmn_height);
    $(".column-c").css('height',cmn_height);
    cmn_height=0;
}
```