# jQuery event when some dom element changed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Is there any way to set a jQuery event when some (any one) element changes its own height?

I really can't find out how I can  fire thi.s

Like:

```
$('body *').onHeightChange(function(){

//do somenthing
});
```

Comment: That would be very intense on the proc. Is there specific elements you want monitored? If so, it's not too hard. You just create a timer and watch for the height to be different.

Comment: Be more specific, what element(s) you doing this on?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery

Comment: nope i don't have specific element cause of it can be a div as a span, random

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can do delegate (called indirect event binding now?) like `$('body').on('resize', '*', function(event) {...})`

Comment: @tungd that is the answer i think, what i'm actually going to do :)

Comment: @tungd I this that is a very costly event listener and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Sorry if I confused anybody, my code snippet will only work with the plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/. It's meant to help when you don't have a specific element (as in the case of the author). The plugin use timer internally and still work when the element is changed by anything rather than just some specific jQuery functions.

@RobinvanBaalen: It does, but not very much as we do not really watch every elements, but wait for the event bubble to the `body`. You can replace `body` with the outer most container of the elements that might change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you do something that changes the height of the element, trigger an event.

```
$("#somelement").slideDown().trigger("heightchange");
```

Now you can bind to that:

```
$("body").on("heightchange",function(e){
    var $el = $(e.target); // the element that has a new height.
});
```

You could even monkeypatch a lot of the jQuery methods that can change the height and have them test the height before and after using the method and trigger the event accordingly. Below is an untested example

```
var topatch = ["slideup","slidedown","height","width","attr","css","animate"];
$.each(topatch,function(i,method){
    var oldfn = $.fn[method];
    $.fn[method] = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this), currHeight = $this.css("height"),
                result = oldfn.apply($this,arguments); 
            // check for promise object to deal with animations
            if ( $.isFunction(result.promise) ) {
                result.promise().done(function(){
                    if ( currHeight != $this.css("height") ) {
                        $this.trigger("heightchange");
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
            if ( currHeight != $this.css("height") ) {
                $this.trigger("heightchange");
            }            
        });
    };
});​
```

Comment: @Badaboooooom this solution doesn't use timers. In my opinion, this is the best solution for your problem.

Comment: i think other guy is right saying i must use **$('body').on('resize', '*', function(event) {...})**

Comment: the resize event only happens on the window, using it for elements will not work unless you apply code similar to mine to trigger it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onresize

Answer (score 2):

I think the only event you can use is the 'DOMSubtreeModified'.

Comment: maybe MutationEvent ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified = Deprecated according to MDN. Use mutation observers instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen to me returns 404 don't know why so :/

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen ok found that problem was the language try this https://developer.mozilla.org/it/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers

Comment: @Badaboooooom well then, if you got auto-forwarded to a 404 page because the original page isn't available in your language, I suppose that's a bug and you should [report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Mozilla%20Developer%20Network&component=Website) it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `jQuery mutate` which has handlers for `width` , `height` and more

http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it, and I know you already have your answer, the trigger thing is great idea, but if you really want a simple plugin on ***all*** possible elements, you could use what I made below.  It's just a simple jQuery plugin that makes use of a timer and a callback function for when a height has changed. See the fiddle for example use. *Warning* Too many elements on the page could cause issues.

## jsFiddle

> **Dirty Plugin**

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.onHeightChange) {
        $.extend({  
            onHeightChange: function(callBack) {
                if (typeof callBack == "string") {
                    switch (callBack.toLowerCase()) {
                        case "play":
                            $.onHeightChange.init();
                            break;
                        case "stop":
                            try { clearInterval($.onHeightChange.timer); } catch(err) { };
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (typeof callBack == "function" || callBack == undefined)
                {
                    $.onHeightChange.callback = callBack;
                    $.onHeightChange.init(callBack);
                }
            }
        });
        $.onHeightChange.timer;
        $.onHeightChange.init = function(callBack) {
            $("body,body *").each(function(i) {
                $(this).data("onHeightChange", { height: $(this).height(), outer: $(this).outerHeight() });
            });
            try { clearInterval($.onHeightChange.timer); } catch(err) { };
            $.onHeightChange.timer = setInterval(function() {
                $("body, body *").each(function(i) {
                    if ($(this).data("onHeightChange").height != $(this).height()) {
                        $(this).data("onHeightChange", { height: $(this).height(), outer: $(this).outerHeight() });
                        if ($.onHeightChange['callback']) {
                            if (typeof $.onHeightChange.callback == "function") return $.onHeightChange.callback .call(this, $(this), $(this).height(), $(this).outerHeight());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 100);
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

> *Example Use*

```
$.onHeightChange(function(ele, height, outer) {
    console.log(ele, height, outer);
});
/*---------------------------------------------*/
$.onHeightChange("stop");
$.onHeightChange("play");
```