# Resize element when another element is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using jQuery to resize an element when the window is resized using:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  topHeight = $("#top").height();
  height = $(window).height() - 210;
  $("#container").height(height);
  $("#g").height(height-25);
});
```

With the topHeight getting the most recent height of the top bar since it can rearrange.

My problem is that I can't figure out a way to resize the #container when the #top changes height. I've tried using `$("#topRow").resize(function() { })`, but it seems as though that doesn't work with elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting when a div's height changes using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch every event when `#top`'s height changes.

If it happens when you resize the window, then you should bind your logic to `window.resize`, so your code in the question should work.

If there are other events when `#top` changes its height, then you should bind the logic there too.

**Update:** in the comments you mentioned that there is a multiple selection field, which can make the `#topRow` element change its height, so that is an event, which you can add your logic to.

**Note:** there is another option. You create a `setInterval` which periodically checks the size of `#topRow` and resises the `#container` if necessary, but I personally don't recommend this solution.

Comment: How do I bind the logic there though? $("#topRow").resize() doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: when does `#topRow`'s height change?

Comment: It changes when the width of the browser is changed OR when too many items are added to a customized multiple selection field.

Comment: @Dyne So, then there are 2 events: window resize, and when an item is added to the multiple selection field. You have to separate the container height updater logic, and add it to both cases.

Comment: @Dyne added another solution in the answer as a note, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: I found [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) which seems to do what I want. I was really hoping to avoid adding more plugins though. It seems to be using a perodic check.

Comment: Yes the periodic check is a solution, as I mentioned in the Note of my answer. Hope you could solve your problem with it!