# get div height after div content load

Tags: jquery, height

I am trying to set the height of one `div` equal to another. I will call them left and right divs. The right `div` content is not always the same and is loaded with jQuery. It is a filter so each time you click a filter, the content change and also the parent div height.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        location.reload();
    });
    var Height = $("#archive").outerHeight();
    $('.recursos-sidebar').css("height", Height);
});
```

The problem is that the left div height is equal to right div when it is empty (no content is loaded).

Somebody know how can I get the height of the right div after the content change each time?

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your site. Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: sorry i will edit the question

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from element clientHeight :

```
document.getElementById("test").clientHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont want to search through the source on your site so here is a crack at what I think you are talking about.

```
<div id="firstdiv"></div>
<div id="seconddiv"></div>

<script>
    $("firstdiv").change(function () {
        var s= $("seconddiv").height();
        $(this).height(sndHeight);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#firstDiv").css('height',$("#secondDiv").height());
});
```

And a demo you find here : http://fiddle.jshell.net/stryd3r/MgnT8/

Comment: take a look here then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery

Comment: i have been reading it but my knowledge on javascript and jquery are poor and dont now what and how to implement these codes.

Comment: just put these code, and in <SCRIPT type=text/javascript> ...</SCRIPT> and add the id 'firstDiv' and 'secondDiv' for both divs that you want it equal , and of course load jquery library.