# jQuery set height of a div to the 'dynamic height' of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs.

```
  <div class="col-1"><p>Content</p></div>
  <div class="col-2"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
```

With their respected content inside each one.

I am trying to set the height of col-2 to be exactly as that of col-1.

I tried this using jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var divHeight = $('.col1').height(); 
        $('.col2').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
    });
```

The problem is that col-1 does not have a height set on it. It has a dynamic height which grows when its content grows. Therefore the above code does not work for it.

Is there any way I can set the min height of col-2 to be equal to the dynamic height of col 1 using jQuery?

Comment: Because the elements classes in your HTML is different than in JS. Check working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2hyyL0vt/)

Comment: @Tushar thats nice, but he specified _"The problem is that col-1 does not have a height set on it"_   I have provided a demo with his requirements in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32109749/4323504

Comment: @LuthandoLoot Right. Here's another [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2hyyL0vt/1/)

Comment: @Tushar nice, I already have that in my answer ;-)

Comment: @AlexZahir You should ask another separate question for this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this works fine for me, its just that your class names are wrong, the class-names should be `.col-1` and `.col-2`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divHeight = $('.col-1').height(); 
    $('.col-2').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/kqhkbhe4/)

**EDIT- *Based on comments:***
You can do all this without using jquery

1. **Flexbox *(not supported in IE 8 & 9)*** - if you apply the flex to the parent div, it will make all its children heights equal:

   ```
    .row{ display: flex;}
   ```
2. **table** - you can give your div's the table layout

   ```
   .row {display: table; }

   .row div { display: table-cell;}
   ```

Comment: can you do a fiddle? Note that we are not specifying a height on .col 1

Comment: @AlexZahir i added the fiddle

Comment: @AlexZahir the div does take full height, the problem is the image, let me see why its doing that, i'll get back to you

Comment: but the background color is  set on the div. i dont want the image to stretch. just show the background color which it isnt doing now

Comment: @AlexZahir it does show your background color, change it to something else, you will see it clear, e.g `background: red;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87439/discussion-between-alex-zahir-and-luthando-loot).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to fix the class names that missed '-' in your jQuery code.

If you want to get the .col-1 height you can do it in several ways, that I will discuss later.

Before that in each case you need to write a function that gives .col-1 height and set .col-2 .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function set_heights(){
        var divHeight = $('.col-1').height(); 
        $('.col-2').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
    }

});
```

Then you just call the function whenever you need...

Some of different ways are :

1. to set interval or timer to call above function once in a period of time you need.

   ```
   setInterval(function(){  set_heights(); }, 100);
   ```
2. use resize event for .col-1 . to call above function when ever .col-1 changed.

   ```
   $('.col-1').resize(function(){
       set_heights();
   });
   ```
3. use bind

> remember!!! for responsive design you need too call above function even when window resized !

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.col-2').css({'minHeight': divHeight+'px'});
```

you can place this in a callback. so it is executed when height is changed.
like this [Detecting when a div's height changes using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery)

Comment: But not in HTML code. In HTML it is `col-1` and `col-2`. Don't you think that might be actual issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a resize event listener, when **col-2** resize, trigger a function to resize **col-2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tb-col1').resize(function(){
       var divHeight = $('.col-2').height(); 
       $('.col-2').css('minHeight', divHeight+'px');
    }
});
```