# How to select element after 400px height of parent div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have main div(parent) with class `.box` and in which more than one (no limit)child div with class `.abc`,
so how can we only select those child div which are occur after 400px height of parent div.
Means,no all child div are select but only select those are after 400px height of parent div.
though,parent div height is not fix.

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="abc"></div>
 <div class="abc"></div>
 <div class="abc"></div>
 .......Unlimited div occure
</div>
```

Comment: Could you paste html code?

Comment: This link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to add a class name to them by taking their `.position().top`:

```
$('.box').find('.abc').addClass(function(){
    return $(this).position().top >== 400 ? "pick" : "";
});

var picks = $('.box').find('.abc.pick'); // gives you all the divs whose
                                         // position top is >= 400px
```

Comment: Nice one, better than mine :)

Comment: @EdenSource both works fine this one just a bit compact.

Comment: Hello @Jai your code working perfectly but after postback it's position count from after Image not from .box div,b'cuz in .bx div containg image with random height then any idea about count position starting from .box div but not aftre image in .box div.you can see snap from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759654/how-to-count-child-div-within-of-its-parent-divs-400px-height-or-how-to-selec

Comment: Though,work perfectly from starting after any poastback it's count position aftert image.

Comment: @GhanshyamLakhani can't get you. It doesn't work or you have some scenario where it stopped working.

Comment: Hello @Jai i explain my problem by two snap , in this you can only look two image not understand any explanation .you can see on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759654/how-to-count-child-div-within-of-its-parent-divs-400px-height-or-how-to-selec

Answer (score 2):

You can use [position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) to detect top position of an element depending on its parent.

```
$(".box .abc").each(function(){
    var topPos = $(this).position().top;
    if(topPos>400){
        $(this).addClass("masked")
    }
});
```

Please see [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kg1vdfbw/)

Comment: it's complete working, "masked" class add completely each box but after postback class are not properly add to each box..any idea about this i'm using update panel

Comment: Could you provide the "post" process relevant code ?

Comment: sorry @EdenSource :it's not possible b'cus of large file,but if you have just idea about this.

Comment: If you are using `.append()` to add your box, you can use something like this https://jsfiddle.net/yv61h844/

Comment: Hello @EdenSource : your code working perfectly but after postback it's position count from after Image not from .box div,b'cuz in .bx div containg image with random height then any idea about count position starting from .box div but not aftre image in .box div.Though,work perfectly from starting after any poastback it's count position aftert image.you can see snap from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759654/how-to-count-child-div-within-of-its-parent-divs-400px-height-or-how-to-selec

Comment: i explain my problem by two snap , in this you can only look two image not understand any explanation .you can see on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759654/how-to-count-child-div-within-of-its-parent-divs-400px-height-or-how-to-selec